# Graph edge traversal algorithm, some edges required, some optional

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic, traversal

I have an undirected graph with all vertices of even degree. In this graph there is a set of edges that must be covered exactly once, and a set of edges that should not be covered at all unless absolutely necessary. I need to find a set of one or more paths through the graph such that all of the required edges are covered exactly once, and the number of undesired edges traversed is minimized. No required edge can be traversed by more than one path, but the undesired edges can be traversed by any number of paths. It is not quite a Eulerian path because there are optional edges.

Each individual path's length is limited by a maximum number of required edges it can cover, although a path can cover any number of undesired edges.

The starting points and ending points need not be the same, but there is a set of possible starting points.

Some of the undesired edges are coincident with the required edges -- that is, a pair of vertices might have both a required edge and an undesired edge between them (although there will never be more than one edge of each type between a given pair of vertices).

What's a good algorithm to start with? Fundamentally, I am looking for an algorithm that can find a path that traverses required edges exactly once and avoids undesired edges when possible (but can traverse them more than once if necessary). I can build on that to do the rest.

Comment: Read Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest - Introduction to algorithms for a detailed introduction to graph algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation; I found a copy at a local bookstore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a subgraph within the original graph, such that it contains all the required edges, with a minimum of undesired edges such that it contains an Eulerian path.

It is known that a graph contains an Eulerian path if and only if it is CONNECTED and has all vertices ( except 2 ) of EVEN DEGREE. This can be ensured by doing the following :

- Start by directly including all the desired edges in the final subgraph. You now have a graph with one or more connected components.

CASE 1 :

- If the number of components in this subgraph is one, (i.e, all the edges are connected to each other ), we only have to ensure that all vertices ( except 2 ) have even degree. Since your original graph does have all vertices of even degree, it is possible to do this, but we also want to take care that the number of edges we add to achieve this is minimum ( since only undesired edges are left to add ).
- One good heuristic way to do this, start from each of the odd degree vertices, and do a BFS ( breadth first search ) till you reach another vertex with odd degree. Do this for all the odd degree vertices, choose the 2 vertices which take the maximum undesired path between them to achieve this, and delete this path. Now the graph will have an Eulerian Path

( One thing to note is that such a pairing of odd vertices is always possible, since no graph can have an odd number of vertices of odd degree )

CASE 2 :

- The subgraph consisting of only desired edges has more than one component. To ensure connectivity, do the following - Take the component with the minimum number of vertices. Do a BFS from each of the vertices, and choose the minimum length path that connects this component to ANY OTHER component.
- Repeat this procedure till all components merge to form a single component. Now for even-ness follow the procedure outlined before for CASE 1.

Comment: Thanks. I left out a point in my original problem; some of the undesired edges are coincident with the required edges -- that is, a pair of vertices might have both a required edge and an undesired edge between them. I still need some time to think about your answer, but I'm wondering if that affects anything. The reason I left it out is because I was generalizing the problem, but now I'm not sure if I generalized it incorrectly or if its still the same problem.

Comment: Do you mean that a single edge can be both required as well as undesired ? Or that a pair of endpoints can have 2 edges between them - one required, the other undesired? If it's the first case, it doesn't matter because even if that edge is undesired, you have to include it within your subgraph since it is required. Even if it is the second case, it poses no problem since you only take the required edge. The undesired edge can be ignored as far as achieving graph connectivity is concerned, and can be included, as required when trying to achieve the even-ness condition.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be reduced into the **Travelling Salesman problem**. Create a transformed graph where the nodes represent compulsory edges and the edge weights represent the number of optional edges that must be traversed to get from one compulsory edge to the other.

Now the problem is to find the shortest path in this transformed graph which goes through all the nodes (aka compulsory edges). This is the TSP, which is NP-hard.

There will be some complications because the paths you can take after a compulsory edge depend on the direction in which you took it. You could solve this by turning each compulsory edge into two nodes, one for each direction. The TSP would then have to visit exactly one node from every pair.

e.g.

```
A===C
|  /
| /             (edges A<->B and B<->C are compulsory, A<=>C is optional)
|/
B
```

Transformed graph:
Nodes = { AB, BA, BC, CB }
Edges = { AB -> BC (cost 0), BA -> CB (cost 1), CB -> BA (cost 0), BC -> AB (cost 1) }

Answer (score 2):

This is NP-hard: an instance of the Hamiltonian path problem can be transformed to an instance of your problem. Therefore, if you know how to solve your problem, you know how to solve the Hamiltonian path problem.

To transform, take a directed graph and double each vertex, say, into a red and a blue vertex. For each former vertex, make all inbound edges go to the red vertex, and all outbound edges go out of the blue vertex. Make a single new edge from the red to the blue vertex. Obviously if you can solve the Hamiltonian cycle problem for this graph, you can do so for the original graph.

Now label all new edges compulsory, all the old edges as optional. Mark a single red vertex as a possible entry point. If there's a solution to your problem, then it consists of a single path, which a Hamiltonian path for the original graph.